# log4net: different logs on different file appenders at runtime

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, log4net

Good morning guys.

I wrote a single istance C# 2.0 app (call it *myapp*).
Myapp is called many times, and at every call generates a sort of "task" that will be executed in a separated thread.
If you call myapp several times in a short time, task are executed in parallel.

Generally I use log4net for logging purposes; I configure it loading an xml file by `XmlConfigurator.Configure(<config>.xml)` at startup, then I use static `LogManager.GetLogger(name)` in every class I need a logger, quite simple.

This scenario is challenging, instead.
I need to do is this: based on one of the args received on every call (call it *arg*), I need to get a different *RollingFileAppender* that logs in a different file, e. g. .log.

Just to make an example:

1st call: `myapp.exe -arg:01`
 - myapp creates thread1
 - set a new RollingFileAppender to 01.log file, if not exists
 - objects used in this thread must log in 01.log file

2nd call: `myapp.exe -arg:02`
 - create thread2
 - set a new RollingFileAppender to 02.log file, if not exists
 - objects used in this thread must log in 02.log file, **but not in log.01**

3rd call: `myapp.exe -arg:01`
 - create thread03
 - get the RollingFileAppender to 01.log file (**it already exists!**)
 - objects used in this thread must log in 01.log file, **but not in log.02**

And so on.
I don't need to leave the configuration of RollingAppender in xml file, I can create it programmatically; my idea is to use a static wrapper class, call it LogHelper, that creates appenders if they do not exist based on *arg*, and that dispatch right ILog istances when needed by objects (in classes I would use something like `ILog log = LogHelper.GetLogger(name, arg`) to get a logger to use instead o default log4net method `LogManager.GetLogger(name)`).
So if I have 2 istances of the same class in 2 different threads, when I log messages goes one per file, depending or *arg* (I will inject *arg* in every object, if needed).

I browse many threads here in StackOverflow, but I can't find a solution.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up with a slightly different solution.
I created a `LogMaster` static class (sorry for poor name) that work similar to the default log4net `LogManager` class.
The difference is that you can get different `ILog` istances based on `arg`: `LogMaster` will create a new `ILoggerRepository` for each different `arg` you will use.

Here the code:

```
#region Usings
using System;
using System.IO;

using log4net;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Config;
using log4net.Core;
using log4net.Filter;
using log4net.Layout;
using log4net.Repository;
using log4net.Repository.Hierarchy;


#endregion


namespace Common.Voyager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A static class that emulates defualt log4net LogManager static class.
    /// The difference is that you can get various loggers istances based from an args.
    /// LogMaster will create a different logger repository for each new arg it will receive.
    /// </summary>
    public static class LogMaster
    {
        #region Const
        private const string RollingFileAppenderNameDefault = "Rolling";
        private const string MemoryAppenderNameDefault = "Memory";
        #endregion


        #region Constructors
        static LogMaster()
        {
        }
        #endregion


        #region Public Methods
        public static ILog GetLogger(string arg, string name)
        {
            //It will create a repository for each different arg it will receive
            var repositoryName = arg;

            ILoggerRepository repository = null;

            var repositories = LogManager.GetAllRepositories();
            foreach (var loggerRepository in repositories)
            {
                if (loggerRepository.Name.Equals(repositoryName))
                {
                    repository = loggerRepository;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Hierarchy hierarchy = null;
            if (repository == null)
            {
                //Create a new repository
                repository = LogManager.CreateRepository(repositoryName);

                hierarchy = (Hierarchy)repository;
                hierarchy.Root.Additivity = false;

                //Add appenders you need: here I need a rolling file and a memoryappender
                var rollingAppender = GetRollingAppender(repositoryName);
                hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(rollingAppender);

                var memoryAppender = GetMemoryAppender(repositoryName);
                hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(memoryAppender);

                BasicConfigurator.Configure(repository);
            }

            //Returns a logger from a particular repository;
            //Logger with same name but different repository will log using different appenders
            return LogManager.GetLogger(repositoryName, name);
        }
        #endregion


        #region Private Methods
        private static IAppender GetRollingAppender(string arg)
        {
            var level = Level.All;

            var rollingFileAppenderLayout = new PatternLayout("%date{HH:mm:ss,fff}|T%2thread|%25.25logger|%5.5level| %message%newline");
            rollingFileAppenderLayout.ActivateOptions();

            var rollingFileAppenderName = string.Format("{0}{1}", RollingFileAppenderNameDefault, arg);

            var rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender();
            rollingFileAppender.Name = rollingFileAppenderName;
            rollingFileAppender.Threshold = level;
            rollingFileAppender.CountDirection = 0;
            rollingFileAppender.AppendToFile = true;
            rollingFileAppender.LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock();
            rollingFileAppender.StaticLogFileName = true;
            rollingFileAppender.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date;
            rollingFileAppender.DatePattern = ".yyyy-MM-dd'.log'";
            rollingFileAppender.Layout = rollingFileAppenderLayout;
            rollingFileAppender.File = string.Format("{0}.{1}", "log", arg);
            rollingFileAppender.ActivateOptions();

            return rollingFileAppender;
        }

        private static IAppender GetMemoryAppender(string station)
        {
            //MemoryAppender
            var memoryAppenderLayout = new PatternLayout("%date{HH:MM:ss} | %message%newline");
            memoryAppenderLayout.ActivateOptions();

            var memoryAppenderWithEventsName = string.Format("{0}{1}", MemoryAppenderNameDefault, station);
            var levelRangeFilter = new LevelRangeFilter();
            levelRangeFilter.LevelMax = Level.Fatal;
            levelRangeFilter.LevelMin = Level.Info;

            var memoryAppenderWithEvents = new MemoryAppenderWithEvents();
            memoryAppenderWithEvents.Name = memoryAppenderWithEventsName;
            memoryAppenderWithEvents.AddFilter(levelRangeFilter);
            memoryAppenderWithEvents.Layout = memoryAppenderLayout;
            memoryAppenderWithEvents.ActivateOptions();

            return memoryAppenderWithEvents;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var arg = "myArg";
var loggerName = "MyLogger";
var log = LogMaster.GetLogger(arg, loggerName);
```

Using this solution you can benefit from default LogManager behavior retrieving `ILog` loggers: if a logger with the same name already exists in a repository, you will get back that istance (recycling behavior).

Thank you @making3 for your suggestions!

Comment: Hi Ferdinando Santacroce, First och all, great research, congrats..
If you use the code from a console application the logging output is also sent to the console, did you know this?

Comment: Thank you, I hope you found it useful. Yes, I know it, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar, where I needed a different log for every instance of a class. You can create logs dynamically with a few steps.

It looks like a [default Logger (Line 97)](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/log4net/Repository/Hierarchy/DefaultLoggerFactory.cs?view=markup) is already defined, but it's internal to their assembly, so it will need to be inherited (as far as I know).

```
public sealed class DynamicLogger : Logger 
{ 
    internal DynamicLogger(string name) : base(name) 
    { 
        base.Hierarchy = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
    } 
}
```

Sample method to retrieve an ILog:

```
public static ILog GetSample(string arg)
{
    var logger = new DynamicLogger(arg);
    logger.Level = Level.All;

    var consoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender();
    consoleAppender.Name = arg;
    consoleAppender.Layout = new PatternLayout(arg + ": %m%newline");
    logger.AddAppender(consoleAppender);

    var newLog = new LogImpl(logger);
    if (_logs.Any(log => log.Logger.Name == newLog.Logger.Name) == false)
        _logs.Add(newLog);

    return newLog;
}
```

Basic usage:

```
var foo = DynamicLog.GetSample("foo");
var bar = DynamicLog.GetSample("bar");
foo.Error("Test");
bar.Error("Test");
```

For your scenario, look at creating a `RollingFileAppender`, and look at the available properties on the object, since this was just an example.

**EDIT:**  Added the below for storing ILog's, and modified the original `GetSample` method above.

Add an array of ILog's and a GetLogger method:

```
private static List<ILog> _logs = new List<ILog>();

public static ILog GetLogger(string name)
{
    return _logs.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Logger.Name == name);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
DynamicLog.GetSample("foo");
var foo = DynamicLog.GetLogger("foo");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I'm trying it with success in a simple console app, with RollingFileAppender.  
I will try with parallel threads now, I'm crossing fingers :)

Comment: There's a way to retrieve a particular logger programmatically, once you have build it with DynamicLog.GetSample()? I don't in wich repository loggers are added; if I call BasicConfigurator.Configure(), log4net builds the default repository with a ConsoleAppender.

Comment: You could always create your own `LogManager.GetLogger` method. All that should be required is creating a list of ILog's, store the log created by `GetSample`, and then have another method such as your own `GetLogger` that will search all ILog's for the specific name, using `log.Logger.Name`. Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: Can't I store logger I create in the main repository, just before returning it in GetSample() method?
And yes, an example would be appreciated. :)

Comment: @FerdinandoSantacroce, I added an example. I believe there is a way to do it, but I would have to mess around with the repository for a bit to give examples of that. I would say the main (negative) difference between my example and storing it, is that `LogManager.GetLogger` will return an ILog regardless if it exists or not.

Comment: ok, got it. I will look for a way to create loggers like you showed to me, using main repository for storing it.