# Create Log4net rolling file which is based on date

Tags: date, dynamic, log4net

I need to create files for 45 separate locations (example: Boston, London, etc). And these file names have to be based on the date. Also can I provide a maximum file size to roll the files and the maximum number of files to roll.

Basically a file name must look like : Info_Boston_(2019.02.25).txt

So far I have come up with the below code to get by date. But I couldn't limit the file size to 1MB. The file grows beyond 1MB, and a new rolling file is not created. Please assist

```
    <appender name="MyAppenderInfo" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="C:\\ProgramData\\Service\\Org\\Info"/>
  <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date"/>
  <param name="DatePattern" value="_(yyyy.MM.dd).\tx\t"/>
  <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %message%n" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
    <levelMax value="INFO" />
  </filter>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

To address your specific post, I would not do this with a config based approach, as it would get rather cumbersome to manage I would think. A more programmatic approach would be to generate the logging instances dynamically.

EDIT: I took down the original to post this reworked example based on this SO post [log4net: different logs on different file appenders at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022467/log4net-different-logs-on-different-file-appenders-at-runtime)

EDIT-2: I had to rework this again, as I realized I had omitted some required parts, and had some things wrong after the rework. This is tested and working. However, a few things to note, you will need to provide the using statements on the controller, to the logging class you make. next, you will need to DI your logging directories in as I have done, or come up with another method of providing the list of log file outputs.

This will allow you to very cleanly dynamically generate as many logging instances as you need to, to as many independent locations as you would like. I pulled this example from a project I did, and modified it a bit to fit your needs. Let me know if you have questions.

Create a Dynamic logger class which inherits from the base logger in the heirarchy:

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Repository.Hierarchy;

public sealed class DynamicLogger : Logger
{
    private const string REPOSITORY_NAME = "somename";
    internal DynamicLogger(string name) : base(name)
    {
        try
        {
            // try and find an existing repository
            base.Hierarchy = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository(REPOSITORY_NAME);
        }   // try
        catch
        {
            // it doesnt exist, make it.
            base.Hierarchy = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.CreateRepository(REPOSITORY_NAME);
        }   // catch
    }   // ctor(string)
}   // DynamicLogger
```

then, build out a class to manage the logging instances, and build the new loggers:

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Config;
using log4net.Core;
using log4net.Filter;
using log4net.Layout;
using log4net.Repository;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class LogFactory
{
    private static List<ILog> _Loggers = new List<ILog>();
    private static LoggingConfig _Settings;
    private static ILoggerRepository _Repository;

    public LogFactory(IOptions<LoggingConfig> configuration)
    {
        _Settings = configuration.Value;
        ConfigureRepository(REPOSITORY_NAME);
    }   // ctor(IOptions<LoggingConfig>)

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures the primary logging repository.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="repositoryName">The name of the repository.</param>
    private void ConfigureRepository(string repositoryName)
    {
        if(_Repository == null)
        {
            try
            {
                _Repository = LogManager.CreateRepository(repositoryName);
            }
            catch
            {
                // repository already exists.
                _Repository = LogManager.GetRepository(repositoryName);
            }   // catch
        }   // if
    }   // ConfigureRepository(string)

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a named logging instance, if it exists, and creates it if it doesnt.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ILog GetLogger(string name)
    {
        string filePath = string.Empty;

        switch (name)
        {
            case "core":
                filePath = _Settings.CoreLoggingDirectory;
                break;
            case "image":
                filePath = _Settings.ImageProcessorLoggingDirectory;
                break;
        }   // switch

        if (_Loggers.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Logger.Name == name) == null)
        {
            BuildLogger(name, filePath);
        }   // if

        return _Loggers.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Logger.Name == name);
    }   // GetLogger(string)

    /// <summary>
    /// Dynamically build a new logging instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the logger (Not file name)</param>
    /// <param name="filePath">The file path you want to log to.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private ILog BuildLogger(string name, string filePath)
    {
        // Create a new filter to include all logging levels, debug, info, error, etc.
        var filter = new LevelMatchFilter();
        filter.LevelToMatch = Level.All;
        filter.ActivateOptions();

        // Create a new pattern layout to determine the format of the log entry.
        var pattern = new PatternLayout("%d %-5p %c %m%n");
        pattern.ActivateOptions();

        // Dynamic logger inherits from the hierarchy logger object, allowing us to create dynamically generated logging instances.
        var logger = new DynamicLogger(name);
        logger.Level = Level.All;

        // Create a new rolling file appender
        var rollingAppender = new RollingFileAppender();
        // ensures it will not create a new file each time it is called.
        rollingAppender.AppendToFile = true;
        rollingAppender.Name = name;
        rollingAppender.File = filePath;
        rollingAppender.Layout = pattern;
        rollingAppender.AddFilter(filter);
        // allows us to dynamically generate the file name, ie C:\temp\log_{date}.log
        rollingAppender.StaticLogFileName = false;
        // ensures that the file extension is not lost in the renaming for the rolling file
        rollingAppender.PreserveLogFileNameExtension = true;
        rollingAppender.DatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        rollingAppender.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date;
        // must be called on all attached objects before the logger can use it.
        rollingAppender.ActivateOptions();
        logger.AddAppender(rollingAppender);

        // Sets the logger to not inherit old appenders, or the core appender.
        logger.Additivity = false;
        // sets the loggers effective level, determining what level it will catch log requests for and log them appropriately.
        logger.Level = Level.Info;
        // ensures the new logger does not inherit the appenders of the previous loggers.
        logger.Additivity = false;

        // The very last thing that we need to do is tell the repository it is configured, so it can bind the values.
        _Repository.Configured = true;

        // bind the values.
        BasicConfigurator.Configure(_Repository, rollingAppender);

        LogImpl newLog = new LogImpl(logger);


        _Loggers.Add(newLog);

        return newLog;
    }   // BuildLogger(string, string)
}   // LogFactory
```

Then, in your Dependency Injection you can inject your log factory. You can do that with something like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<LogFactory>();
```

Then in your controller, or any constructor really, you can just do something like this:

```
    private LogFactory _LogFactory;

    public HomeController(LogFactory logFactory){
        _LogFactory = logFactory;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        ILog logger1 = _LogFactory.GetLogger("core");
        ILog logger2 = _LogFactory.GetLogger("image");
        logger1.Info("SomethingHappened on logger 1");
        logger2.Info("SomethingHappened on logger 2");
        return View();
    }
```

This example will output:

```
2019-03-07 10:41:21,338 INFO  core SomethingHappened on logger 1
```

in its own file called `Core_2019-03-07.log`

and also:

```
2019-03-07 11:06:29,155 INFO  image SomethingHappened on logger 2
```

in its own file called `Image_2019-03-07`

Hope that makes more sense!

Comment: @sm101 if this answers your question, please mark it as answered.